# How to show [0,1] images in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, matplotlib, image-processing, imshow

I have a `numpy.ndarray` in Python that has value in `[0,1]` period.

```
[[0.01558322 0.01558322 0.01558322 ... 0.01558322 0.01558322 0.01558322]
 [0.01558322 0.01558322 0.01558322 ... 0.01558322 0.01558322 0.01558322]
 [0.01558322 0.01558322 0.01558322 ... 0.01558322 0.01558322 0.01558322]
 ...
 [1.         1.         1.         ... 1.         1.         1.        ]
 [1.         1.         1.         ... 1.         1.         1.        ]
 [1.         1.         1.         ... 1.         1.         1.        ]]
```

When I show this `numpy.ndarray` with `plt.imshow` it returns this image:

[image]

And also when I use `imshow` in Matlab to show this image it shows this image:

[image]

I want to know why `matplotlib` cant show like as Matlab?

My Python code is here:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

Image = Image.open('sample.jpg')
Image=np.array(Image)
Image=np.double(Image)

Lenght=np.shape(Image)

ImgR=Image[:,:,0]
ImgG=Image[:,:,1]
ImgB=Image[:,:,2]

ParamR=np.zeros((1,2))
ParamR[0,0]=np.mean(ImgR)-np.mean(ImgR)/2
ParamR[0,1]=np.mean(ImgR)+np.mean(ImgR)/2

ParamG=np.zeros((1,2))
ParamG[0,0]=np.mean(ImgG)-np.mean(ImgG)/2
ParamG[0,1]=np.mean(ImgG)+np.mean(ImgG)/2

ParamB=np.zeros((1,2))
ParamB[0,0]=np.mean(ImgB)-np.mean(ImgB)/2
ParamB[0,1]=np.mean(ImgB)+np.mean(ImgB)/2


Main_Param=np.zeros((1,2))
Main_Param[0,0]=(ParamR[0,0]+ParamG[0,0]+ParamB[0,0])/3
Main_Param[0,1]=(ParamR[0,1]+ParamG[0,1]+ParamB[0,1])/3


def S_Function(x,a,b):
   if x<=a:
       y=0
       
       
   elif x>a and x<=(a+b)/2:
       
       y=2*(((x-a)/(b-a))**2)
       
   elif x>(a+b)/2 and x<=b:
       y=1-2*(((x-a)/(b-a))**2)
       
   else:
       y=1
   return y

New_ImageR=np.zeros_like(ImgR)
New_ImageG=np.zeros_like(ImgG)
New_ImageB=np.zeros_like(ImgB)
for i in range(0,Lenght[0]):
   for j in range(0,Lenght[1]):
       
           New_ImageR[i,j]=S_Function(ImgR[i,j],Main_Param[0,0],Main_Param[0,1])
           New_ImageG[i,j]=S_Function(ImgG[i,j],Main_Param[0,0],Main_Param[0,1])
           New_ImageB[i,j]=S_Function(ImgB[i,j],Main_Param[0,0],Main_Param[0,1])


           
Out_Image=np.zeros_like(ImgR,dtype='double')            
for i in range(0,Lenght[0]):
   for j in range(0,Lenght[1]):
       
       Out_Image[i,j]=np.sum([New_ImageR[i,j],New_ImageG[i,j],New_ImageB[i,j]])

Out_Image=Out_Image/np.max(Out_Image)
plt.imshow(Out_Image,cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

my matlab code is here:

```
clc;
clear;
close all;

Img=imread('sample.jpg');
Img=double(Img);
ImgR=Img(:,:,1);
ImgG=Img(:,:,2);
ImgB=Img(:,:,3);


[m,n,p]=size(Img);

ParamR(1)=mean(ImgR(:))-mean(ImgR(:))/2;
ParamR(2)=mean(ImgR(:))+mean(ImgR(:))/2;

ParamG(1)=mean(ImgG(:))-mean(ImgG(:))/2;
ParamG(2)=mean(ImgG(:))+mean(ImgG(:))/2;

ParamB(1)=mean(ImgB(:))-mean(ImgB(:))/2;
ParamB(2)=mean(ImgB(:))+mean(ImgB(:))/2;

Param=[(ParamR(1)+ParamG(1)+ParamB(1))/3,(ParamR(2)+ParamG(2)+ParamB(2))/3];
NImgR=zeros(m,n);
NImgG=zeros(m,n);
NImgB=zeros(m,n);



for i=1:m
    i
    for j=1:n
        InputR=double(ImgR(i,j));
        NImgR(i,j)=smf(InputR,Param);
        
        InputG=double(ImgG(i,j));
        NImgG(i,j)=smf(InputG,Param);
        
        InputB=double(ImgB(i,j));
        NImgB(i,j)=smf(InputB,Param);
    end
end

Out_Img=zeros(m,n);
for i=1:m
    for j=1:n
        Input=[NImgG(i,j),NImgB(i,j),NImgR(i,j)];
        Out_Img(i,j)=sum(Input);
        
    end
end
Out_Img=Out_Img/(max(max(Out_Img)));
imshow(Out_Img)
```

Thanks so much.

Comment: More details on the difference please. I see the size difference. Please use the same size and compare.

Comment: What happens if you compare between the original images using matplotlib and matlab? If these are the same, I guess the problem is within your processing.

Comment: @AajKaal I import Out_Image from python to matlab and check all pixels they are same but visualization is different. I will edit my question and will share my matlab code.

Comment: @itaishz it's not possible because I check all parameters in two matlab code and Python code.

Comment: It is the size and y ticks only. At the most if you increase the y ticks, go beyond 1000 on Y you will see exact same as other.

Comment: @AajKaal I edit my question and add my matalb code to question. they are same but different visualization.